# Is it different DC power jack for each different laptop?

Tags: laptop, port, dell-inspiron, adapter, charger

I have replaced my DC power jack (DC301015T00) by local shop owner with another DC power jack (DC30100U00D). But my laptop default charger (45W) is not working(charging symbol coming but not charging my battery,battery percentage not increasing instead decreasing). Instead if the local shop owner use another laptop charger(which is 60W) it works(battery charging percentage increases).
How my charger not working after changing DC power jack? Each laptop has unique DC power jack for each version of laptop?

**This is my DC power jack (DC301015T00) my laptop default power jack**

[Picture of DC power jack - https://i.stack.imgur.com/v02ZB.jpg](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v02ZB.jpg)

**Error After changing DC power jack from (DC301015T00) to (DC30100U00D)**

[error after laptop switched on - https://i.stack.imgur.com/jcrk3.jpg](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jcrk3.jpg)

Comment: It can be. Different Jack's have different center pin and outer shield spring sizes meaning that you can end up with one or the other not making contact if you try and fit the wrong jack in the wrong plug. There are enough different types so you want to be sure you have the right one.

Comment: @Mokubai I don't think this is a connection problem - I think it has to do with the cable not having connectors for negotiation when talking to the charger.

Comment: I'm not an expert, but I have seen Dell laptops throw up messages about power supplies before - very often this is something that can be turned off in the BIOS.   I believe some Dell laptops have circuitry that talks to the power supply to check if its genuine Dell and the charge rate.   From the message you are getting I expect this is coming in to play here.   It sounds like your computer store has put in the wrong part - and it should fall to them to source and replace it with the correct one.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

There's two things to mention..

Re Does the DC Jack fit. Obviously not every single laptop model is going to have a different DC jack, otherwise you'd have hundreds of thousands of different DC Jacks.  But it's not that all laptops use the same DC Jack either.

And independent from whether "it fits".

You should check the power requirements. Volts, Amps, Watts.

And anyhow, what you are getting there, shown in that image, isn't an error message, it's a warning message.. Dell laptops can give a warning message even if a power supply is fine, but if it's not a Dell manufactured power supply. I have a dell laptop somewhere with an unofficial power supply and I just hit ENTER on a message like that, about how dell says they can't identify the power supply.

Really if you picked up a random power supply and plugged it in then I wouldn't trust it.  If a shop put it in then it should be ok  so you can probably be "lazy" and just hit ENTER.

If you want to make some effort then you can check the voltage watts and amps.(though it's a safe bet that a shop isn't going to get that wrong). and if you want to go nuts and really go over the top, there might be other ways to test the power supply further.

Comment: Yes problem is with my 45W adapter. Brought a new 45W adapter works fine now.